# How to add data label annotation to a single bar based off name in a Seaborn barplot Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe producing the following plot:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10,1,'a'], ['matt', 15,5,'b'],['nick', 18,2,'b'],['luke', 12,6,'b'],['geoff', 20,10,'a']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Score','Category']) 
df

# Create plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.27,11.7,))
df = df.sort_values(['Attempts'],ascending=False)
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="Attempts", y="Name", data=df,
            label="Total", palette=["b" if x!='nick' else 'r' for x in df.Name], ax=ax)

# Annotate every single bar with its value
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    ax.text(width - 1,
            p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 1 + 0.1,
            '{:1.2f}'.format(width),ha="center")
```

[Seaborn plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbnXJ.png)

I want to include the data label annotation for only `'Nick'`(i.e. in this instance the value 18 on the bar itself) which is the highlighted bar and have no label annotations on the rest of the bars. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Here is my solution:

First I reset the index of your df and then found the index number of the row matching the criteria (in this case `nick`):

```
# Create plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.27,11.7,))
df = df.sort_values(['Attempts'],ascending=False)
#Reset index values
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
#Return the index number of name required
indexno = df[df['Name'] == 'nick'].index
#Create array
a = np.array(indexno)
a= a[0]
print(a)
```

Which gives me:

```
1
```

(the 2nd row in your `df`)

Then I found all of the `get_width` values:

```
#Plot
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="Attempts", y="Name", data=df,
            label="Total", palette=["b" if x!='nick' else 'r' for x in df.Name], ax=ax)

# Final all width values in plot
values = []
for i in ax.patches:
    values.append(i.get_width())
    
print(values)
```

which returns:

```
[20.0, 18.0, 15.0, 12.0, 10.0]
```

Now the final loop to display only the values where the criteria match (so the 2nd value in values (18)).

```
#Final loop to annotate only the row where width equals the value of `nick`
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    x = values[a]
    if width==x:        
        ax.text(width - 1,
                p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 1 + 0.1,
                '{:1.2f}'.format(width),ha="center")
plt.show()
```

[image]

full code:

```
 # Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10,1,'a'], ['matt', 15,5,'b'],['nick', 18,2,'b'],['luke', 12,6,'b'],['geoff', 20,10,'a']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Score','Category']) 
df

# Create plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.27,11.7,))
df = df.sort_values(['Attempts'],ascending=False)
#Reset index values
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
#Return the index number of name required
indexno = df[df['Name'] == 'nick'].index
#Create array
a = np.array(indexno)
a = a[0]
print((a))

#Plot
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="Attempts", y="Name", data=df,
            label="Total", palette=["b" if x!='nick' else 'r' for x in df.Name], ax=ax)

# Final all width values in plot
values = []
for i in ax.patches:
    values.append(i.get_width())
    
print(values[a])

#Final loop to annotate only the
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    x = values[a]
    if width==x:        
        ax.text(width - 1,
                p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 1 + 0.1,
                '{:1.2f}'.format(width),ha="center")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create only the labels you want to highlight and set them to 'set_yticklabels()'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10,1,'a'], ['matt', 15,5,'b'],['nick', 18,2,'b'],['luke', 12,6,'b'],['geoff', 20,10,'a']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Score','Category']) 

# Create plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.27,11.7,))
df = df.sort_values(['Attempts'],ascending=False)
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
g = sns.barplot(x="Attempts", y="Name", data=df,
            label="Total", palette=["b" if x!='nick' else 'r' for x in df.Name], ax=ax)

# Annotate every single bar with its value
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    if width == 18.0:
        ax.text(width - 1, p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 1 + 0.1, '{:1.2f}'.format(width),ha="center")
    else:
        pass

#label = ['','nick','','','']
#g.set_yticklabels(label)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for your response - I'm not sure if I explained myself clearly enough but I am speaking about the data label annotation on the bar itself (i.e. the number of attempts), rather than the label on the y axis of name. Sorry for the confusion !

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so my comprehension was lacking. Does this fit with the intent of your question? I have updated the code and images.